# How to store Global Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, global

In my Workbook i have an Array which stores machines. With a button i am able to add some machines to the array.

The final array is used in three other buttons, each button is on a different worksheet. My question now is, how do i store the array global with its changing value?

this is my code for adding some value to the array:

```
Private Sub Add_Machine_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim Machine() As Variant
    Dim DataRange As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("MachineTemplate")
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set DataRange = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
    Set Cell = DataRange.Find(What:=ComboBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Cell Is Nothing Then
        ws.Range("A" & lastrow + 1) = ComboBox1.Value
    End If

    ReDim Machine(DataRange.Cells.Count)
    For Each Cell In DataRange.Cells
        Machine(x) = Cell.Value
        x = x + 1
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Right now i use the same code for the other three buttons. is there a way i can store this code as global?

I allready tried it in the WorkbookSheet like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Machine() As Variant
Public ws As Worksheet
Public lastrow As Long
Public DataRange As Range

ws = Worksheets("MachineTemplate")
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set DataRange = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
ReDim Machine(DataRange.Cells.Count)
x = 0
For Each Cell In DataRange.Cells
    Machine(x) = Cell.Value
    x = x + 1
Next Cell
```

But i know that this is totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a Global Array for this. Since you are using `Redim` without `Preserve`, then it means it is getting initialzed everytime from the range `DataRange`

Also to create the array, you do not need to loop trough it everytime. You can directly create a 2D array in one line

```
Dim Machine as Variant
Machine = DataRange.Value
```

You may also want to see [VBA Arrays And Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

I usually avoid using Global variables. They get reset very easily during runtime if an error happens.